# Do we remove tags from a question when the tag is referenced but isn't relevant?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

For example in this question:

[image]

Although python is referenced in the question, it's not a relevant detail in terms of solving it. The question is about call blocking in lua, and the user just happens to be trying to call block a python script.

In this situation is removing the python tag in an edit appropriate?

Comment: It *could* be relevant if the python host would have unusual behavior that makes this difficult.  But it doesn't, so no need to alert 600K users about this question.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is relevant in this case, but if you are sure that it is irrelevant, then it is correct to remove it.

Answer (score 17):

In this *specific* case, I would agree with [Nicol Bolas' answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370680/157247): Err on the side of leaving it.

In the *general* case, if the tag is truly irrelevant, remove it. Examples:

- A question asking how to do X in (say) C#.Net and giving an example of how they do it in (say) Java and tagging [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java): I'd remove the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag. Yes, their example is in Java, but the question isn't about Java, it's about C#.Net.
- A question about how to do something within a browser and tagging an OS. Unless there's truly something OS-specific about it, I'd remove the OS tag.
- Similarly, a question about how to do something within a browser and tagging [google-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome), [firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox), [microsoft-edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge), and [safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/safari). I'd remove those tags, because the question isn't about those browsers, specifically, it's about how to do something in a browser *in general*.

Answer (score 12):

> In this situation is removing the python tag in an edit appropriate?

... maybe?

The question is asking about how to tell if the Python script is finished. That may or may not involve something Python-specific. Can Python spawn other processes and not tie its own execution to the execution of those processes? If so, then the answer becomes more complicated.

Or maybe it doesn't. Does the user even care about such circumstances?

I would err on the side of leaving it.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion the question would've been more useful had it asked how to execute external commands one after the other with no mention of Python, apart from maybe including it in the example command (and having the asker maybe later ask about Python specifically if the general answer doesn't work).

But it asked specifically about Python, so you shouldn't be quick to edit that out, in case there's an answer that would be specific to Python.

If you come back after some time (a few days or weeks or whatever) and see a bunch of answers (one of which is accepted) which are all clearly have nothing to do with Python, you could consider editing it out at that stage, to make it more useful as a reference post for duplicates. This would include removing the tag, but also editing the title and body to ask the more general question (but without removing the specific details, e.g. "I execute an external command (a Python script) from my browser...").

My argument for saying this is:

- We can't really close a more general question as a duplicate of a less general one, even if the less general one only has more general answers. A user would be less inclined to accept their question is actually a duplicate if we do this.
- If someone *is* wondering about Python specifically (and the more general solutions don't work in their case), a question with only general answers won't help them anyway, and they'd be better off asking a new question (or adding a bounty, but ... meh).

Answer (score 1):

If in your opinion it appears that they are just spamming the tags to get more visibility then remove the tag and explain in the comment they should not spam the tags.

If the tag has no specific relevance to the question and would be considered noise to that tags followers then I would remove it.

In this case the [raspberrypi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raspberrypi) and [raspbian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raspbian) are irrelevant as well and should have been removed as well as the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) since they are noise to those tag followers.

This question is about the [shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell) and probably [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) because those tag followers are the ones that should see this so they can answer it or mark it as the duplicate that it probably is.

This question is also closeable because there is no MCVE, what little code that is provided is out of context and vague.